# keeping same url for desktop / mobile web pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I have dynamic website which has complex design structure so can't go for responsive design. So I have decided to keep separate layout pages for desktop & mobile device & code behind will be the same. But how can I keep same url structure for both. e.g. www.sitename.com/products/power-bank/6000mah so in both mobile & desktop pages will be different but url will be the same.I don't want to use any subdomain for mobile site.

Here I am using custom routing as well in global.asax

```
private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("index", "index", "~/index.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("shop1", "{category}", "~/shop1.aspx"); 'actual url sitename.com/power-banks
    routes.MapPageRoute("shop2", "{category}/{name}", "~/shop2.aspx"); 'actual url sitename.com/power-banks/6000mah
}
```

Comment: you are better off getting a subdomain, loading different pages depending on device costs a lot of time and resources.

Comment: Will it increase load time?

Comment: Would you be OK having both HTML in two different divs on a single page?

Comment: yes that would be also fine

Comment: @SUN anything you're going to do will increase load time if you're not going with a responsive design.